# getting error : Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined in node js

Tags: node.js

i have created sample page, and when i run my page `node airbnb-library.js` i am getting error, `Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined` can anyone please help me why i am getting this error ? here i have attached my code, can anyone please look my code and help me to resolve this issue ? any help will be really appreciated...

db.js

```
const config = require('../config.json');
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = db = {};

initialize();

async function initialize() {
    // create db if it doesn't already exist
    const { host, port, user, password, database } = config.database;
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({ host, port, user, password });
    await connection.query(`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`${database}\`;`);

    // connect to db
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, password, { host: host, port: port, dialect: 'mysql' });

    // init models and add them to the exported db object
    db.User = require('../users/user.model')(sequelize);
    db.Airbnb = require('../users/airbnb.model')(sequelize);

    // sync all models with database
    await sequelize.sync();
}
```

airbnb-library.js

```
const  http  = require("http");
const requestapi = require('request');
const airbnb = require('airbnbapijs')

async function test() {
    const airbnbdata = await airbnb.newAccessToken({ username: 'dino@pushideas.com', password: 'Christmas2016!'})
    console.log(airbnbdata);
}
let airbnbdata = test();
```

main.js

```
const config = require('../../../config.json');
const airbnb = require('airbnbapijs')
const requestapi = require('request');
const  http  = require("http");

 async newAccessToken({ username, password } = {}) {
try {
            await this.airbnblogin({"email":username,"password":password});    

        } catch (e) {     
            console.log(e);
  }
}

async airbnblogin(params) { 
        let account = await db.Airbnb.findOne({ where: { airbnb_email: params.email, } })
}
```

Comment: I don't see where db.js is imported

Comment: Please remove a duplicate of this question